# Can someone tell me how to load different assets folder instead of normal assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am working on a Rails project where we need to use different assets folder but I am not able to figure it out how is that possible. By default rails load assets folder and in my case, I have to load assets_v2. Can someone give me some hint how can I proceed for this task

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Add following to your `assets.rb` file.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets_v2')
```

OR

You can use `vendor` folder. For example, I want to put `iCheck/custom.css` file in assets, then I will put it 
on this path: `vendor/assets/stylesheets/iCheck/custom.css`

Comment: I want to override the rails default assets load behavior. Instead of assets it should load assets_v2

Comment: By default rails will look into assets folder and it will try to load the assets from there instea of assets_v2